# Enabling or Disabling Options during Runtime

Tags: java, command-line-interface, picocli

I'm trying to make an interactive cli using Picocli, and want to have some options appear after a(n) action/requirement has been completed. Is there a way I can do this without using the CommandSpec?

Option to be shown before

```
@Option(names = {"-c","--chooseDevice"}, description = {"Choose Devices"})
    private boolean chooseDevice;

--
some code that will initialize a device
--
```

Option to be show after

```
@Options(names = {,"-d", "--deviceCommand", description = "some device command")
    private boolean deviceCommand;
```

Output should be

```
//before choosing device
-c  --chooseDevice "Choose Devices"

//after choosing device
-c  --chooseDevice   "Choose Devices"
-d  --deviceCommand  "some device command"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the `hidden` attribute of an option at runtime, but it does require using the programmatic API (like the `CommandSpec` class).

Picocli 4.0 added the ability to remove options from a `CommandSpec`, so you can replace it with a copy of the option that has a different value for its `hidden` attribute.

Something like this:

```java
CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine(new MyApp());

// replace the old "--device" option with a different one that is not hidden
CommandSpec spec = cmd.getCommandSpec();
OptionSpec old = spec.findOption("--device");
OptionSpec newDeviceOption = OptionSpec.builder(old).hidden(false).build();
spec.remove(old);
spec.add(newDeviceOption);

cmd.execute(args);
```

Please see [GitHub issue #736](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/736#issuecomment-504857199) for more details.